# Perdida del sistema de archivos tras bootear con dd

Tags: linux

tenia una duda en cuanto al booteo de imagen en un dispositivo. Cuando se utiliza el comando dd de linux, lo que haces es transferir exactamente la imagen al dispositivo. Naturalmente, antes de bootear la imagen, le creaba un sistema de archivo (por defecto fat32, por mayor compatibilidad) al dispositivo, pero ahora tras usar el comando dd, el sistema de archivos aparece como "desconocido". La iso funciona bien, pero no sabría que es ese desconocido. Cuando utilizo algunos programas para bootear, por ejemplo rufus, se mantiene el formato del sistema de archivos. ¿Esto por que pasa? ¿Deveria dejarle una cavezera o algo para no perder el formato?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sistema de archivos de la imagen? Porque el comando 'dd' copia tal cual la imagen y puede ser que no sea 'fat32' y no te la reconozca!

Comment: Es el ultimo netinstall de debian (debian-9.5.0-amd64-netinst), con la version live de mate y tambien me pasaba con el gparted.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs7ho.png

Comment: Parece que la información del tipo de filesystem está escrita antes de la primera partición (por una particularidad de Windows 7 y 8), pero la bandera ('flag', que aparece traducida en GParted como Opciones) dice claramente que es 'msftdata', correspondiente a Microsoft Basic Data Partitions (BDP), para particiones NTFS y FAT.

Comment: Ah, genial, ahi tiene mas sentido. Igual e creado mas particiones y le e mandando otros sistemas, estos tambien lo tienen antes de las particiones? Eso estaria en los primeros 2048 sectores?

Comment: El manual de Gentoo es bastante explícito para ese tipo de detalles: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation/es#Tablas_de_particionamiento

Comment: A buenisimo! si, se ve bien detallado. Gracias